# Box Api :: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: box-api

I am getting the error

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Here is the the code.

```
String sFolderURL = @"https://www.box.com/api/";
string Headers = string.Format("BoxAuth api_key={0}&auth_token={1}", api_key, authToken);
String sParam = "2.0/folders/0";
String sURL = sFolderURL + sParam;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", Headers);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Any chance you can send what the output of your program looks like?  Also, have you verified that your auth-token is still valid for other calls?

Answer (score 2):

A 401 is only returned in the case of sending an expired/invalid access_token. You probably need to either

1. Refresh the token you have
2. Go through the auth process from the start to get a valid token